# Docker – Compile maven project inside docker container & run it from there

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker

I have a project running Vue & Spring Boot that I need to create a `docker-compose.yml` file to run `mvn clean install` to generate the `.jar`, and then build a "new" image from another Dockerfile with that said `.jar` inside the docker container.

This is the Dockerfile that needs to be run once the `mvn clean install` is completed:

```
FROM java:8

ENV WKHTML_VERSION 0.12.4

# Builds the wkhtmltopdf download URL based on version numbers above
ENV DOWNLOAD_URL "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/${WKHTML_VERSION}/wkhtmltox-${WKHTML_VERSION}_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget && \
    wget $DOWNLOAD_URL && \
    tar vxf wkhtmltox-${WKHTML_VERSION}_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz && \
    cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/local/bin/ && \
    cp wkhtmltox/lib/* /usr/local/lib/ && \
    rm wkhtmltox-${WKHTML_VERSION}_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz

# @see https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/
COPY   server/target/redo-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","app.jar"]
```

So the build steps need to be something like this:

- Install node + maven / pull those images
- Install `postgresql` & pull that image
- Run `mvn clean install` & generate `.jar`
- Build new image from abovementioned `Dockerfile` and run it

I am new to `docker-compose` so I am having troubles setting this up in the correct execution order.

The reason I need to do this is due to a problem with the production pipeline not having `node or npm`, which is needed to run the full maven application (`Vue.js` and `Spring Boot` app), which is why it needs to be compiled from inside the Docker container

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could point me in the right direction, let alone – is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by writing a multi-step build as my Dockerfile. I am installing node as a dependency in the client's pom.xml file.

```
# Install maven and copy project for compilation
FROM maven:latest as builder

COPY pom.xml /usr/local/pom.xml
COPY server /usr/local/server
COPY client /usr/local/client
WORKDIR /usr/local/

RUN mvn clean install


FROM openjdk:8
ENV WKHTML_VERSION 0.12.4
# Builds the wkhtmltopdf download URL based on version numbers above
ENV DOWNLOAD_URL "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/${WKHTML_VERSION}/wkhtmltox-${WKHTML_VERSION}_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget && \
    wget $DOWNLOAD_URL && \
    tar vxf wkhtmltox-${WKHTML_VERSION}_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz && \
    cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/local/bin/ && \
    cp wkhtmltox/lib/* /usr/local/lib/ && \
    rm wkhtmltox-${WKHTML_VERSION}_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz

COPY   --from=builder /usr/local/redo/server/target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Comment: it takes a lot of time to build in a maven image. Is there any way to reduce that time ?